# ExtJS 4: Apply Defaults to all columns in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Now that ExtJS 4 got rid of the ColumnModel object, how do you apply default config options to all columns in a grid?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Courtesy of Stevil on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133149-ExtJS-4-Grid-Column-default-config-options&p=621675&viewfull=1#post621675):

```js
var mygrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    //... store config, other config..., 
    columns: {
        items: [{
            header: 'Kd.-Nr.',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: 65,
            hidden: false
        }, {
            header: 'Firma',
            dataIndex: 'company_name'
        }],
        defaults: {
            sortable: true,
            hidden: true,
            width: 100
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this with `align: 'center'` in `defaults` and it didn't work :(
I am using ExtJS 4.1.3

Comment: The code above was written for ExtJS 4. I don't know if anything has changed in 4.1